# Encoded & truncated content returned from CKEDITOR control

Tags: ckeditor

This is not a question on encoding/decoding html like you might expect.  We have a strange situation using CKEDITOR where we are getting back a dorked up string of html. This has happened 7 times out of about 1000 submissions and has always been inside tables.

The html returned by the CKEDITOR getData() method looks great for the first +-4000 characters (that length may be irrelevant, I just noticed they all seem to break down in the range of 3900 - 4100 characters).

Then at some point in the middle of a table we run into this situation (line breaks and indents are mine):

```html
<table>
  ...Lots of good tr's and td's...
  <tr>
    <td>Borrower Name</td>
    <td>&lt;td style=&quot;pad&lt;/td&gt; &lt;/tr&gt; &lt;/tbody&gt; &lt;/table&gt; &lt;/body&gt;
    </td>
    ...Missing subsequent td's in this row
  </tr>
  ...Missing subsequent tr's in this table
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Notice that a padding style got chopped off along with the rest of its corresponding attribute & element. In fact, the entire rest of the table was cut out, all subsequent cells and rows.

The curious thing about all of this is that the user who submits the content does not see the corruption, it isn't noticed until the user who reviews it takes a look.

We've interviewed the users who have submitted the data, and they don't seem to be doing anything advanced: no copy/paste from word, they are not manipulating the tables (ie, we give them the table as part of a template, they just fill it out).

The worst part about this is that I have no instructions for reproducing.  It just seems to crop up once out of several dozen attempts.  I've tried everything: mashed buttons; pasted foreign characters; hooked it up to an automated test runner for 2 hours; tried insulting it. Cannot figure out how they are doing this.

This is on CKEDITOR 4.3, IE 8.

FWIW: we have multiple instances of CKEDITOR on the page.

Comment: Does it happen only on IE8?

Comment: We've only seen it happen on IE8.  That's not to say that it wouldn't happen on 9 or later given the right keystrokes or moon phase.

Comment: I should also say that we only have about 5 people using this part of the application, all of whom are on IE8.  This feature will be rolled out to a larger group of users in the next month or two, so I think time will tell whether it is limited to IE8 or not.  But I sure would like to get this fixed before then.

Comment: Hmm... tough problem. It may be a completely random bug in IE8, but there is a small chance that it is a bug in CKEditor. You could try logging what `editor.editable().getHtml()` returns when invalid HTML is submitted. That may give an answer if this is a bug in IE's implementation of `innerHTML`, what in case of IE8 is probable. My another idea is that some antivirus could do that - I saw issues where antiviruses were polluting or breaking data submitted by a user, because some stupid heuristic thought that... I don't know :D.

Comment: Antivirus, interesting.  Yeah, the more I think about it the more I suspect it's something in IE8's innerHTML.  Debugging through CKEDITOR, I see that it cracks open the html and does some manipulation to it, but I can't see any place that it would be encoding characters even if it did get confused on the structure.

Appreciate the thoughts Reinmar.